# Connection error in the transport layer of initializing provider

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to connect to an analysis services database in SSIS using a specific user name and password.

I'm getting the message

> Error in initializing provider. An error was encountered in the transport layer.

The peer prematurely closed the connection.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you connecting to SSAS?

Answer (score 2):

Are your rights properly set up in Analysis Services?
Assuming when you create the new AS connection through SSIS you click the 'Edit' button in the Add New Analysis Services Connection window and type in your username and password it should work. Are you able to log in through SQL Management Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing/reinstalling [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services 9.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=50b97994-8453-4998-8226-fa42ec403d17&displaylang=en) (for 2005) or [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services 10.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=B33D2C78-1059-4CE2-B80D-2343C099BCB4&displaylang=en) (2008)